# How to get a list (or subset) from an OpenCL Kernel?

Tags: list, return-value, return, opencl, subset

I have a large array with 2^20 ulongs on it.  This little OpenCL kernel flows through it like a charm. Yet, I have absolutely no idea (and google hasn't helped here) how to return a small number of items (2^10) from it.

What I'm looking for is a fixed-sized list with at most 1024 items that have hamming distance (popcount) smaller than a given number.  The list order doesn't matter, so perhaps I should be asking for a subset of these 2**20 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is a way, through some hacks.  [I forked pyopencl.algorithm and created a new method, sparse_copy_if()](https://github.com/Alex-Linhares/sdm/blob/master/pyopenCL_Tests/my_pyopencl_algorithm.py), that returns the exact-sized buffer I need, *as if it were a list with items being appended to*.  I will document it, and submit a patch to Andreas.

If your buffers are too large, though, there is a way to improve performance even more: I followed [Rick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/676506/rick-rainer-ludwig)'s suggestion above, created a hash table, and threw the desired results in there.  (Note that there's always risk of collision, so the hash table buffer/array has to be orders of magnitude larger than your expected output).

Then, I run sparse_copy_if() *on the hash table buffer* and receive nothing but a perfectly-sized buffer.

In conclusion:

I have a kernel scanning a 1,000,000-sized buffer.  It computes results for all of them but doesn't separate the results I want.

These desired results are then thrown in a ~25,000 buffer (hash table, significantly smaller then the original data).

Then, by running sparse_copy_if() on the hash table buffer, you get the desired output---almost as if it were a list in which items could have been appended to.

sparse_copy_if(), of course, has the overhead of creating the perfectly-sized buffers, and copying data to them.  But I've found that this overhead generally compensates, as you are making now (low-latency) transfers of small buffers/arrays from device back to host.

[Code for testing sparse_copy_if() performance versus copy_if().](https://github.com/Alex-Linhares/sdm/blob/master/pyopenCL_Tests/sparse_copy_if_test.py)

Answer (score 3):

Since the output is expected to be much smaller than the input, using a global index in the output through atomic access will not be too ineffective.  You need to pass a buffer containing a single uint, initially set to 0:

```
__kernel void K(...,__global uint * outIndex,...)
{
  ...
  if (selected)
  {
    uint index = atomic_inc(outIndex);  // or atom_inc if using OpenCL 1.0 extension
    out[index] = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Out of interest is it possible to write out[atomic_inc(outIndex)] = value; instead? or will the compiler not understand that?

Comment: Excellent answer! Has helped me to make my kernel return a list of results. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A list as such is not supported with OpenCL. OpenCL is a kind of standard C with some extensions and some limitation. You can only operate on buffers (aka arrays).

What you might look for is a global memory buffer which you need to allocate before you run the kernel. In this you can put your results in and with an clEnqueueReadBuffer you can retrieve your results.